# How to use the "Contains" function with an external list

Tags: xslt-2.0

My XSLT is validating a language code, but for some reason it doesn't work.  It does an include of another xsl file that contains all possible language codes.

```
<xsl:include href="inc/iso639-2.xsl"/>
```

This file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="iso639-2">
        <xsl:text>aar</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>abk</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ace</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ach</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ada</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ady</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>afa</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>afh</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>afr</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ain</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>aka</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>akk</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>alb</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ale</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>alg</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>alt</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>amh</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ang</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>anp</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>apa</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>ara</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>arc</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>arg</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>arm</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>arn</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>arp</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>art</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>arw</xsl:text>
...
```

Then I have this template match which gets executed, but the test is successfull even though a language code such as "zzz" is not in the above list.

```
   <xsl:template match="etdms10:language | etdms11:language">
        <language>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(text()) = 3 and contains($iso639-2, lower-case(text())">
                    <languageTerm type="code" authority="iso639-2b">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </languageTerm>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                ...
```

Any idea why my xsl:when is successful with language codes such as "zzz" , when it should not be? I really ensured language codes such as "zzz" aren't part of this list.
Thanks
Thanks

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not clear whether you expect the variable to contain a sequence of text nodes or just one long string.

Comment: Just a random opinion: Putting data into an XSLT is _suboptimal_. Only its creator will know why he's not used an XML file for it which would ease querying.